# AngularJS $http post using the same JSON for multiple calls to a custom API

Tags: angularjs, http

I am connecting to a custom JSON API (local embedded device) using my own AngluarJS service.

It works fine for single calls.

However when I do multiple calls it sends the last call every time, so I'm sure I have a problem with my scope but I just can't figure out where.

(examples edited for brevity)

I have many custom calls called like this:

```
CustomService.get(name).then(function () {
```

And are defined like this:

```
module.service('CustomService', function (CustomSendJson) {
   var self = this;
   this.getResponse = null;
   this.get = function (name) {
      ...
      command.data.name = name;
      return CustomSendJson.send(
         {
            'json': command,
            'success': function () {
               self.getResponse = CustomSendJson.response.data;
            }
         });
   };
...
});
```

Which all use a service:

```
module.service('CustomSendJson', function ($http) {
   var self = this;
   this.query = null;
   this.response = null;

   this.send = function (options) {
      var json = options['json'];
      var successFn = options['success'];
      ...

      return $http.post('/api', json).then(
          // process success and failure
```

I have checked the json at the point of creating the post

```
return $http.post('/api', json).then(
```

and it is correct each time, but when the http post is actually sent, network traffic shows it is sending the last call every time.

I tried to create a Plunker of the problem using timeouts and defers but all I could create was one that worked every time, except in a corner case that doesn't apply here!

http://plnkr.co/edit/YuYcCyUOABwcjRaIldYI?p=preview

I'm hoping someone can see where I made the mistake.

**Edit: calling code**

```
// with listResponse containing data for "9_1", "11_1" and "16_1"
for (var index in listResponse) {
    var name = listResponse[index].name;
    console.log('Start loop for '+ name);
    ...
    (function (name) {
        console.log('annon call for '+ name);
        CustomService.get(name).then(function () {
            console.log('Get return for for '+ name);
            var data = CustomService.getResponse;
            (function(data){
                $scope.outputList[name] = {
                    'name': data.name,
                    ...
                };   
            }(data));
        });
    }(name));
}
```

Comment: What generates these multiple calls? What does `send last call` really mean?

Comment: In my example multiple http post messages are required each with a different name; "9_1", "11_1" and "16_1". So I call it 3 times (or 'n' times because it is variable). At the point of inspection (at the http call) the names are correct "9_1", "11_1" and "16_1" but the messages on the wire are "16_1", "16_1", "16_1" which means the variable `json` from `return $http.post('/api', json).then(` 
So it has something to do with $http.post perhaps.

Comment: Where's the code? Sounds like you have a `for` loop or something and aren't using a closure for indexing

Comment: In CustomService, can you post where command is defined and set before getting passed to CustomSendJson.send? If it is getting defined outside of the CustomService.get method, then the problem is going to be that you are updating the object on each subsequent request after passing the reference.

Comment: Unfortunately the place it is set is the `command.data.name = name;` line shown, the bit before is just building the rest of the command.  I should re-iterate that the names are correct at each stage (console.log and inspection), it is correct in the CustomService.get and then again inside the CustomSendJson.send, in fact right at the line `return $http.post('/api', json).then(` it is still set to the correct names.  It is either that this variable `json` is changing each call (I can't figure out why), or this is internal to the `$http.post`, I'm confused.

Comment: Many thanks, I rebuilt this whole code section from scratch testing at each stage and simplifying it and I don't have the problem anymore. It must have been a scope issue but I'm not sure what.  Sorry for wasting your time.